# Hide/ show list items when clicking on h4 in .aspx page

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I'm building a newsletter archive which is sorted in different categories. The markup looks like this:

```
<h4>Category 1</h4>
                <ul>
                   <li><a href="../Newsletter1" target="_blank" class="button_sharp left">Newsletter 1</a></li>
                   <li><a href="../Newsletter2" target="_blank" class="button_sharp left">Newsletter 2</a></li>
                   <li><a href="../Newsletter3" target="_blank" class="button_sharp left">Newsletter 3</a></li>

                </ul>

 <h4>Category 2</h4>
                <ul>
                   <li><a href="../Newsletter1" target="_blank" class="button_sharp left">Newsletter 1</a></li>
                   <li><a href="../Newsletter2" target="_blank" class="button_sharp left">Newsletter 2</a></li>
                  <li><a href="../Newsletter3" target="_blank" class="button_sharp left">Newsletter 3</a></li>

                </ul>
```

Now there will be quite a lot of categories and newsletters so I want the newsletters to be hidden until the user clicks on the Category `h4`. And to hide again when clicked again.
I've tried this function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $('h4').click(function() {
   $(this).find('ul').toggle();
 });
</script>
```

I guess this isn't working because I would have to wrap the `h4` in a `ul` but this results in an error. Any suggestions?

Comment: use `next()` to find the next `ul` after the `h4`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the jQuery .next function, so it will look for the next `<ul>` class after each h4 tag here is a quick demo demo:

```js
(function( $ ) { 
$('h4').click(function() {
   $(this).next('ul').toggle();
 });
}).apply( this, [ jQuery ]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h4>Category 1</h4>
<ul>
  <li><a href="../Newsletter1" target="_blank" class="button_sharp left">Newsletter 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="../Newsletter2" target="_blank" class="button_sharp left">Newsletter 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="../Newsletter3" target="_blank" class="button_sharp left">Newsletter 3</a></li>

</ul>

<h4>Category 2</h4>
<ul>
  <li><a href="../Newsletter1" target="_blank" class="button_sharp left">Newsletter 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="../Newsletter2" target="_blank" class="button_sharp left">Newsletter 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="../Newsletter3" target="_blank" class="button_sharp left">Newsletter 3</a></li>

</ul>
```

And a
[Jsfiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/v4cgqarn/)